# Can I tell where my django app is mounted in the url hierarchy?

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I need to redirect my clients to another endpoint in my django app.  I know I can use relative urls with `request.build_absolute_uri()` to do this, but I am searching for a generic solution that doesn't require the redirecting handler to know its own place in the URL hierarchy.

As an example, I have handlers at the following two URLs:
`https://example.com/some/other/namespace/MY_APP/endpoint_one`
`https://example.com/some/other/namespace/MY_APP/foo/bar/endpoint_two`

Both handlers need to redirect to this URL:
`https://example.com/some/other/namespace/MY_APP/baz/destination_endpoint`

I would like for `endpoint_one` and `endpoint_two` to both be able to use the exact same logic to redirect to `destination_endpoint`.

My app has no knowledge of the `/some/other/namespaces/` part of the URL, and that part of the URL can change depending on the deployment (or might not be there at all in a development environment).

I know I could use different relative urls from each endpoint, and redirect to the destination URL.  However, that required that the handlers for `endpoint_one` and `endpoint_two` know their relative position in the URL hierarchy, which is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why not use relative urls? Case like this is exactly why they were invented. I don't think you can figure out from within the app what url it is mapped to as it is a web server configuration. You can only get file path, but it is not related to url in general case.

Comment: relative URLs are a possible solution, but I'd like something that doesn't require the handler to know its own URL.  So, the endpoint might be mounted at `MY_APP/foo/my_endpoint`, but I'd like it to be able to use the exact same redirect logic as if it is mounted at `MY_APP/my_endpoint` - so it doesn't need to know where it is, only where it needs to go

Comment: @serg I'm going to re-word the question to make it a bit clearer what I'm trying to do.  you're right; as the question is written it's a no-brainer to solve with relative urls.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research and talking with coworkers, I realized that `reverse` does exactly what I need.